# Phusion Passenger Standalone web server in Ruby - Gem load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Ubuntu 16.04. LTS (using Vagrant)
Ruby 2.2.0 (using rbenv)

I have error during starting `passenger`.
I googled it but nothing relevant on Github or SO so far.

```
bundle exec passenger start
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/vagrant/any_app/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /home/vagrant/any_app/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
[ N 2019-02-10 15:51:30.0945 20261/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 20302 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'compass-rails'.
App 20302 output: Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass
App 20302 output: Backtrace for gem load error is:
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:348:in `try_sass'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/sass/rails3_shim.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/root.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/util.rb:11:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/util.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/version.rb:2:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/version.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `try_sass'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/sass.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core.rb:63:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/any_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output: config.ru:3:in `require'
App 20302 output: config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
App 20302 output: config.ru:1:in `new'
App 20302 output: config.ru:1:in `<main>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 20302 output: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
App 20302 output: Bundler Error Backtrace:
App 20302 output:  (Bundler::GemRequireError)
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/any_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
App 20302 output:     config.ru:3:in `require'
App 20302 output:     config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
App 20302 output:     config.ru:1:in `new'
App 20302 output:     config.ru:1:in `<main>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 20302 output:     /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2019-02-10 15:51:31.0686 20261/Tj age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/vagrant/any_app: The application encountered the following error: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'compass-rails'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:348:in `try_sass'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/sass/rails3_shim.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/root.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/util.rb:11:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/util.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/version.rb:2:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.25/lib/sass/version.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/haml/util.rb:347:in `try_sass'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/haml-3.1.8/lib/sass.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core.rb:63:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/core.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/vagrant/any_app/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/home/vagrant/any_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
```

Gems:

```
Using rake 12.3.2
Using clive 1.2.1
Using process_runner 0.0.4
Using hitimes 1.3.0
Using contextual_exceptions 0.0.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.4
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using bundler 1.14.6
Using builder 3.0.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.7
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.55
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using awesome_print 1.8.0
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.3
Using json 1.8.6
Using thor 0.20.3
Using sass 3.4.25
Using callsite 0.0.11
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using chunky_png 1.3.11
Using client_side_validations 3.2.8
Using moped 1.4.5
Using origin 1.0.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using haml 3.1.8
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ffi 1.10.0
Using connection_pool 2.2.2
Using daemons 1.3.1
Using diff-lcs 1.3
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using god 0.13.7
Using kramdown 1.17.0
Using metaclass 0.0.4
Using redis 3.3.5
Using require_reloader 0.2.1
Using rspec-support 3.8.0
Using rusen 0.1.0
Using yard 0.9.18
Using rake-compiler 0.9.9
Using timers 4.1.2
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using methadone 1.9.5
Using rack-cache 1.8.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using rack-contrib 1.8.0
Using passenger 6.0.1
Using rack-protection 2.0.5
Using sprockets 2.2.3
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using better_errors 2.5.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.8.0
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using bootstrap-sass 3.1.0.2
Using compass-core 1.0.3
Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
Using zen-grids 2.0.3
Using nokogiri 1.9.1
Using oily_png 1.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 4.1.20
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using thin 1.7.2
Using mocha 1.8.0
Using rspec-core 3.8.0
Using rspec-expectations 3.8.2
Using rspec-mocks 3.8.0
Using celluloid-essentials 0.20.5
Using celluloid-extras 0.20.5
Using celluloid-fsm 0.20.5
Using celluloid-pool 0.20.5
Using celluloid-supervision 0.20.6
Using activesupport 3.2.22.5
Using sidekiq 5.0.3
Using mail 2.5.5
Using xpath 3.1.0
Using coffee-filter 0.1.3
Using compass 1.0.3
Using celluloid 0.17.4
Using inflections 3.3.0
Using activemodel 3.2.22.5
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using actionpack 3.2.22.5
Using activerecord 3.2.22.5
Using activeresource 3.2.22.5
Using mongoid 3.1.7
Using actionmailer 3.2.22.5
Using railties 3.2.22.5
Using simple_form 2.1.3
Using client_side_validations-mongoid 3.1.0
Using blueprint-rails 0.2.0
Using sass-rails 3.2.6
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using jquery-rails 2.3.0
Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
Using meta_request 0.6.0
Using rails 3.2.22.5
Using rspec-rails 3.8.2
Using client_side_validations-simple_form 2.1.0
Using bootstrap-sass-rails 3.1.0.0
Using compass-rails 3.0.2
Using rspec-rails-mocha 0.3.2
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Appendix:**

environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'

# Initialize the rails application
AnyApp::Application.initialize!
```

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"

require 'require_reloader'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module AnyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"] + Dir["#{config.root}/funcs/**/"]

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # watch all .rb files recursively under modules/module1/ dir
    config.watchable_dirs["#{config.root}/funcs"] = [:rb]

    # To autoreload bots/bots.rb
    RequireReloader.watch :funcs
  end
end

require 'application_defs'
```

**Latest Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sass"

gem 'rails', '~>3.2'

gem 'rack', '~>1.4'

# Database module
gem 'origin', '~>1.0.11'
gem 'moped', '~>1.4.3'
gem "mongoid", '~>3.1.2'

# For convenient styling macros and SASS
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.5'
#gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
gem 'blueprint-rails', '~> 0.2'

# To interpret Coffeescript in HAML
#gem 'coffee-filter', '~> 0.1'

# JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'

# Enable HAML format views. Prettier than ERB format views.
gem "haml"

# For deployment. Phusion Passenger integrates the rails app. with Apache.
gem 'passenger'

# To manage background processes
gem 'god'

# Improved forms
gem 'simple_form'

# Instant form validation
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'client_side_validations-mongoid'

# Improved logging output
gem 'awesome_print'

# Simple exception email notifications
gem 'rusen'

# For CLI client application
gem 'methadone'

# For better errors in WAPP
gem 'contextual_exceptions'

# To run background process
gem 'process_runner'

# For background process communication
gem 'sidekiq', "~> 2.13.1"

# To add bots without restarting the server
gem 'require_reloader'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  # JavaScript library
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem "bootstrap-sass-rails"
  gem 'zen-grids'

  # compass uses this for sprites
  gem 'chunky_png'

  # native c library for png routines to speed up chunky_png
  gem 'oily_png'
end

group :development do
  # YARD documentation library
  gem 'yard'

  # To interpret markdown
  gem 'kramdown'

  # gem 'rack-mini-profiler'

  # Better error information
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'

  # Not strictly necessary but makes
  # testing through a VM network much faster
  # because WeBrick needs a line of configuration
  # changed, otherwise it's impossibly slow 
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'mocha', require: false
  gem 'rspec-rails-mocha', require: false
end
```

**UPDATE:**

- upgraded haml
- upgraded passenger
- upgraded compass-rails
- removed coffee-filter
- downgraded ruby to 2.1.10
- upgraded jquery-rails to 3.0.4 (see [Warning: This gem is
  incompatible with the jquery-rails gem before version 3.0.0!](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/))

See current `Gemfile` updated in my question at the **"Latest Gemfile"** section.

**Latest result:**

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.slider'
  (in /home/vagrant/any_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass:2):
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___560869471232658965_47192790759720'
```

Comment: Would you be able to post your `config/application.rb` and `config/environment.rb`, please?

Comment: @ViktorNonov Sure, see appendix of my question!

Comment: For the Sprockets exception: yout should change `//=require jquery.ui.slider` to `//= require jquery-ui/widgets/slider`, check the doc of the gem jquery-ui-rails - https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/

Comment: @ViktorNonov in which file should I change it? I made it in application.js, but the error remained.

Comment: in `application.sass` put `//= require jquery-ui`. This might be good for another question btw, since it's not related to the original exception.

Comment: @ViktorNonov True, I accept your answer. I will post here soon the next question's link. Thank you for your help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception:

```
uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass
```

shows that Sass is not defined yet, which means that the `sass` gem hasn't been `require`'d yet.

In order to fix this you should put `gem 'sass'` before `gem 'haml'` in your `Gemfile`.

Edit:

The version of `haml` that you're using is `3.1.8`, is version in which the gem still provides `sass` engine. It's gonna be better to upgrade to `haml >= 4.x` if you can.

In this case you won't need `coffee-filter` gem anymore, because the haml gem has built-in support for CoffeeScript in haml templates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if you look at the gem list you can see, that sass is installed before haml. When I update haml I get a following error: "undefined method `lazy_require' for Coffee::Filter::Coffeescript:Module (NoMethodError)"

Comment: @Geeocode The order that they are installed in does not matter and do not mirror the way that gems are declared in the Gemfile. I meant that the order in your Gemfile matters for the `Bundler` class which requires them when your application boots. It's weird that it didn't work, because I was able to reproduce the same issue on my machine, by changing the order of the gems.. Can you post your Gemfile, please?

Comment: Okay. I added more info in the Edit section. Basically in your case the best option is to upgrade haml to `>= 4.x` and then remove the `coffee-filter` which gives you that exception, since it's not needed for `haml >= 4.x`  as you can see in its Readme https://github.com/paulnicholson/coffee-filter

Comment: Viktor, thank you, basically both of us get the coffee-filter removal solution and I did it, but... see my latest update.